# Python binary conversion to hex

Tags: python, string, binary, hex, gzip

I'm trying to convert a binary I have in python (a gzipped protocol buffer object) to an hexadecimal string in a string escape fashion (eg. \xFA\x1C ..).

I have tried both

```
repr(<mygzipfileobj>.getvalue())
```

as well as

```
<mygzipfileobj>.getvalue().encode('string-escape')
```

In both cases I end up with a string which is not made of HEX chars only.

```
\x86\xe3$T]\x0fPE\x1c\xaa\x1c8d\xb7\x9e\x127\xcd\x1a.\x88v ...
```

How can I achieve a consistent hexadecimal conversion where every single byte is actually translated to a \xHH format ? (where H represents a valid hex char 0-9A-F)

Comment: Do you want/need the `\x` in front of every hexadecimal byte or would an output of `0123AB7F` instead of `\x01\x23\xAB\x7F` also okay? Or do you prefer another formatting?

Comment: I know how to have the 0123AB7F output, what I'm looking for is actual \x01\x23\xAB\x7F format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\xhh` format you often see is a *debugging aid*, the output of the `repr()` applied to a string with non-ASCII codepoints. Any ASCII codepoints are left a in-place to leave what readable information is there.

If you must have a string with **all** characters replaced by `\xhh` escapes, you need to do so manually:

```
''.join(r'\x{0:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in value)
```

If you need quotes around that, you'd need to add those manually too:

```
"'{0}'".format(''.join(r'\x{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in value))
```

Comment: Thanks.
I have tried that out I have an issue : **zero length field name in format**. Python 2.6

Comment: @codeJack add in a 0 to the placeholder: `{0:02x}`. Python 2.6 is rather ... outdated.