# having an issue to convert decimal to hex

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, hex

I want to communicate with a serial port (usb ), To be able to do that, i need to send hex value to the board, for example my code is:

```
elements = [133,128,128,128]
registerValue = bytearray(elements)
ser.write(registerValue[0:4])
print (registerValue[0:5] , "here")
```

and it will print:

```
bytearray(b'\x85\x80\x80\x80') here
```

which is correct in my case, but i need to have the [130, 50] as well, when I am doing the same, intead of having

```
bytearray(b'\x82\x32') here
```

it will print

```
bytearray(b'\x822') here
```

I tried to understand the code and it seems that it will return the ascii value
can any one help me with this issue???

Comment: This is working as expected—in the representation of a string or byte string, Python will print out the ASCII value for a byte if it is printable, and in this case `chr(50)` is "2" so that is printed. It is just how it is represented when you print it out in this fashion, but the byte array itself is perfectly fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316698/python-binary-conversion-to-hex

Comment: You do not have to send hex values to a USB! You have to send *bytes*. How these byte values are *represented* is something entirely different.